# Run a program on a specific port of my machine

Tags: java, sockets

I need to run a setup on my windows machine with 1 master and 2 workers on the same machine.
I have setup the master to run on port 1111 and workers to run on 2222 & 2223.
How can i access these ports to run my programs?
I dont want to install VmWare or any virtual desktop.

I want to know how can I run a program on a specific port of my machine.
If it requires a socket program, can someone provide a sample JAVA API for the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot run a program on a Port, what you can do is make your program listen to a port. Check [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) from Oracle for more information regarding Java Sockets

Comment: Sun? You mean Oracle? (but the unwise one though, since they're suing Google for Dalvik). LOL

Comment: making my program listen to the port isnt going to work for me..
i need to simulate a master-slave setup and different program has to be run on the master and slave machines.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: Yeah you are right, it is a matter of habbit lol. 

@user462203: If that is the case, then, you need to give a more detailed explenation.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Sockets API will allow you to specify the port number.

See here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29